# cp command throwing error in crontab

Tags: cron

I have the following command in my crontab to copy a file named 'data' into an existing directory named 'Archive', with a date stamp appended to it.  When I run it on the command line manually, it works fine.

```
01 0  * * * cp /home/data /home/Archive/data.$(date +%F)
```

But when cron runs the above (under the same user), the file does not copy, and I get the following error:

> cp: 0653-437  2018 is not a directory

Comment: Which version of `date` is installed, and what's your locale?

Comment: please run `date +%F` and tell us what you get. it seems that you get a space character somewhere and the `cp` command thinks that you're trying to copy several files into a directory.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a shell issue.
Try putting that command inside of a script that starts

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and execute the script manually to make sure it works, then try executing it in cron.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be there is no such directory.
 This oneliner will handle dir creation for you:

`01 0  * * * export NEWDIR=/home/Archive/data.$(date +%F) ; mkdir -p "$NEWDIR";  cp /home/data "$NEWDIR"`

Comment: The question specified that the `Archive` directory already exists, and the error shown is the one that results from trying to copy multiple sources.  When there's a single source, and the destination doesn't yet exist, then `cp` should try to create that destination automatically (or show a different error about the source).